# restoreOverrideCursor is not stopping the cursor from showing progress

Tags: python, pyqt

restoreOverrideCursor is not stopping even after process is completed. Is it mandatory to use setOverrideCursor and restoreOverrideCursor only once for a particular application.

I am using both set and restore cursor at the beginning of each if condition in my code. Please let me know how to solve this.

```
if a == "Option1":
     QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.WaitCursor))
#Some part of the code
     QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()

if a == "Option2":
     QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.WaitCursor))
#Some part of the code
     QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()
```